# How to Add Serial Number Field in MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an `Invoice` Form in MS Access 2007. This form have a subform named `InvoiceLines` having fields `SerialNumber`, `ItemNumber`, `ItemName`, `ItemQty` etc. I want to add Serial Numbers in this form. I have added `=CurrentRecord` property to showing current row number. But this property showing  number “1” in all rows. Is there any easiest way to add serial numbers in MS Access form?

[image]

Comment: By Serial Number do you mean an Autoincrementing ID?

Comment: No, I just want to add row number (or record number) for each row. And if I delete a row then the row numbers should automatically updated just like in excel sheet.

Comment: A row number only has meaning if the dataset is sorted - are you sorting your dataset? And if so, by which field? If you are simply looking to display an incrementing number in your form, why do mention your `SerialNumber` field so frequently in your question?

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. What do you mean by `if I delete/sort any row then the sequence of serial numbers should not affect`? Should `Wheat Flour` of invoice `1` always be serial number `3`? Or does it for example depend on sorting?

Comment: I mean, if I delete row of `Serial Number 2` then the `serial number 3` will takes the place of 2 and will automatically change to 2. Actually the `Serial Number` is for counting rows

Comment: And what about sorting?

Comment: The Serial numbers should showing in ascending order (1, 2, 3...) same as record number if sorting change. I means If I sort `ItemName` field in descending order and  `Wheat Flour` will showing on top then the `SerialNumber` should hardly showing in ascending order (1, 2, 3...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, now knowing what you want here is my solution:

In the subform add this procedure:

```
Private Function SerialNumber(ByVal sourceForm As Form) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Catch

    SerialNumber = Null

    With sourceForm.RecordsetClone
        .Bookmark = sourceForm.Bookmark
        SerialNumber = .AbsolutePosition + 1
    End With

Done:
    Exit Function

Catch:
    If Err.Number <> 3021 Then MsgBox Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "SerialNumber"
    Resume Done
End Function
```

Then add a textbox control in this subform and set its `Control Source` to `=SerialNumber([Form])`.

That would fulfill all your needs.

Remark: If you delete a record in the subform you would have to refresh the subform to update the serial numbering.

Comment: I am not much familiar with coding. How to add this procedure in subform? And in `=SerialNumber([Form])` do I have to write subform name in the place of `[Form]`? like `=SerialNumber([InvoiceLines])`

Comment: No, exactly `=SerialNumber([Form])`. To add the code to the subform: Open the subform in `Design View`. Then in the ribbon page named `Design` press `View Code`. In the now open code window paste the code in the free area and save it. Switch back to the Access form design window, close the form. Done

Comment: Great..! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by changing the datasource of the form and add there a new column.

Assuming that your table is named `Table1` and your primary key is `ID`, you could use a sub query to calculate it dynamically:

`SELECT Table1.*, (Select Count(*) FROM Table1 as X WHERE X.ID < Table1.ID)+1 AS Serial FROM Table1`

Comment: I have inserted this query in `SerialNumber` field but it displaying an error `#Name?`

Comment: In `SerialNumber` field? The idea was to use it as the datasource of a form, not of a control. Maybe you should create a new query with this SQL first to see what its output is.

Comment: And be aware, that `Table1` and `ID` presumably have to be renamed to fit your environment.

Comment: I have created a new query `Query1` and using it as control source of my form's `SerialNumber` field. like `=[Query1]![SerialNumber]`. But it showing error `#Name?`

Comment: When I open this query in table view then query works fine but not in my form

Comment: `InvoiceLines` is the form where you want the serialnumbers to be displayed, right? So the query should be in the **forms** recordsource, not in any controls recordsource. To get the new calculated field visible in the subform, you need a control on the form, bound to that field `Serial`.

Comment: Actually I want to add `SerialNumbers` for each invoice starts from 1. This query adding serial numbers and If I generate 2nd Invoice then the serial numbers continuing from 1st invoice. And new record row also not appearing after adding this query.

Comment: Ok, rollback: I understood you want the serial number for invoice lines. But you want them for invoices, is that correct? So this serial number shouldn't be calculated on the fly but be persistent to each invoice in the invoice table. Each invoice needs to have its own unique serial number (invoice number). Is that correct? It's important (at least now) that you edit your question now and add samples of tables and values you have, and what you need.

Comment: I have added a screenshot with some detail.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot & description, it appears that you are describing an `AutoNumber` field.

Such a field cannot be edited by the user and will be automatically populated by MS Access with an integer unique within the dataset. This may be used as a primary key for the dataset and will be unaffected by sorting or deletion of records.

If your current `SerialNumber` field already contains data, you will not be able to change the datatype of this field to `AutoNumber`. As such, you will need to delete your existing `SerialNumber` field before adding a new field with datatype of `AutoNumber`.

Comment: In case of Auto Number, When I generate 2nd Invoice then the Auto number will starts from number 4. But I want to add serial numbers in each invoice which starts from 1. Just like record numbers showing in footer.